# MySQL OperationalError 2006 with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy during audio file upload

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, whisper

I am encountering an issue while uploading audio files using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy in my Python application. The code is designed to handle user authentication, validate user IDs, and save metadate to a MySQL database. However, I am consistently getting the following OperationalError:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))")


I have already checked the MySQL server status, examined error logs, and reviewed connection parameters, but the issue persists. The error occurs during the audio_processor.save_audio_file_to_db method, which interacts with the MySQL database using SQLAlchemy.
```

````
def save_audio_file_to_db(self, user_id: str, audio_file: UploadFile) -> str:
    log.info("Inside save_audio_file_to_db")
    try:
        # Generate a unique ID for the audio file
        audio_id = str(uuid4())

        # Create user-specific and audio-specific folders
        user_folder = f"user_{user_id}"
        audio_folder = os.path.join(COMMON_AUDIO_FOLDER, user_folder, audio_id)
        os.makedirs(audio_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # Save the uploaded audio file to the specified path
        audio_path = os.path.join(audio_folder, audio_file.filename)
        with open(audio_path, "wb") as audio_file_object:
            shutil.copyfileobj(audio_file.file, audio_file_object)

        # Call remove_silence function to remove silence from the audio before saving it to the path
        remove_silence(audio_path)

        # Calculate audio length using pydub
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path)
        audio_length_in_seconds = len(audio) / 1000.0  # Convert milliseconds to seconds

        # Get current UTC time and convert it to Sri Lankan time
        utc_now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        sri_lankan_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Colombo')
        lk_now = utc_now.astimezone(sri_lankan_timezone)

        # Metadata for the audio file
        metadata = {
            "size": os.path.getsize(audio_path),
            "utc_date": str(utc_now),
            "lk_date": str(lk_now),
            "audio_length_seconds": audio_length_in_seconds,
        }

        # Log metadata information to a file
        log_path = os.path.join(audio_folder, "metadata_log.txt")
        with open(log_path, "w") as log_file:
            for key, value in metadata.items():
                log_file.write(f"{key}: {value}\n")

        # Create an instance of the Audio model
        audio_instance = Audio(
            id=audio_id,
            user_id=user_id,
            path=audio_path,
            utc_date_created=metadata["utc_date"],
            lk_date_created=metadata["lk_date"],
            audio_length_seconds=metadata["audio_length_seconds"]
        )
        # Add the audio instance to the database and commit the changes
        self.db.add(audio_instance)
        self.db.commit()
        log.info("Save Audio in Db audio_id: "+audio_id)
        return audio_id```
````

Comment: that is usually an indicator that the query took to long to process and must be optimzed, you should run the raw query and see if ndexes are used with ÈXPLAiN SELECT`

Comment: This can also happen if the size of the row being inserted is too large - i.e. if it's above 1MB, it'll run afoul of MySQL's default max packet size. It doesn't seem like you're adding the file contents to MySQL itself, but verify what the contents of `Audio` is before the insert happens. Can you replace the insert with a select and it works approriately, or do you still get the same error?